# Can only wizards create / hatch a Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

There doesn't seem to be much mention about how to create / hatch a Basilisk except for:

> Of the many fearsome beasts and monsters that roam our land, there is none more curious or more deadly than the Basilisk, known also as the King of Serpents. This snake, which may reach gigantic size, and live many hundreds of years, **is born from a chicken's egg, hatched beneath a toad**. Its methods of killing are most wondrous, for aside from its deadly and venomous fangs, the Basilisk has a murderous stare, and all who are fixed with the beam of its eye shall suffer instant death. Spiders flee before the Basilisk, for it is their mortal enemy, and the Basilisk flees only from the crowing of the rooster, which is fatal to it."
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

Is there any references to if the breeder has to be a wizard, or can muggles or non-human magical beings do so as well?

Answer (score 5):

#### Anyone can hatch a Basilisk, as far as we know.

I've got the original (not the screenplay) *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, and it doesn't say that the process must be carried out by a Witch or Wizard, only that it was discovered by a Wizard, ([Herpo the Foul](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Herpo_the_Foul)), before being promptly banned.

It's highly unlikely that such a thing would ever occur in nature, and I can't imagine any Muggle ever thinking to hatch a Chicken's Egg underneath a Toad of all things, so accidental Basilisks aren't going to be commonplace.

However, what is interesting is the following sentence:

> The Ministry of Magic has said that all chicken coops in the Wizarding world are subject to police inspection in order to thwart Basilisk breeding.

It seems perfectly sensible at first glance, but why only chicken coops in the Wizarding world? Perhaps the chicken egg in question must be from a magical chicken? And perhaps the toad must be a magical toad? Either way, it seems odd that the Ministry only checks up on Wizards' chicken coops. A Muggle-Born wizard that has grown up on a muggle farm wouldn't be subject to inspection, and anyone could walk into a supermarket, buy a few dozen eggs and go down to their local pond or something. Accidental Basilisks might not be a common occurrence, but it seems to me like anybody could very easily hatch themselves a Basilisk if they knew how and really wanted to.

In short, nobody's ever said that there has to be anything special about the breeder, the egg or the toad, so it's entirely possible that a muggle could hatch themselves a Basilisk.

Comment: It would be a very unfortunate school experiment. "Now class, today we're going to observe the effects of hatching an egg under different animals to see the importance of a Mother Hen for the egg's wellbeing. Now.... oh, what's this? Gather round and _look closely_ everyone, the egg under the toad appears to be hatch-OH MY G-" Ministry Cleanup Squad: "Tch, Muggles and their 'Science', amirite?"

Comment: For some reason I _can_ think of a Muggle (or anyone, for that matter) who would want to test the legend by placing a chicken egg under an unsuspecting toad - for scientific skepticism. _Hold my beer_...

Comment: In common legend, it's actually a Cockatrice that is the result of hatching a Chicken's Egg under a Toad. A Basilisk is in fact the reverse, and requires one to hatch a Toad or Serpent egg under a Chicken. This is different from the HP universe, where both creatures are from chicken eggs, but the Basilisk is hatched under a toad and a Cockatrice hatched under a serpent.

Comment: But I see your point. If I were a Dark Wizard versed in technology, I'd start a challenge on Facebook/YouTube and get people to hatch chicken eggs under toads for the lols. And you know those crazy teens would do it, too, just for more views. Oh, the hell that could be unleashed...

Comment: @DisturbedNeo just one nitpick, but a supermaket egg can never hatch (it hasn't been fertilized by a male), its merely a by product of the chicken not  finding a mate. In that scenario few muggles would have access to a 'fertilized' chicken egg to actually try it. This significantly reduces the chance of a muggle doing it even if they tried it.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Real-life laboratory scientists create chimaeras all the time. Chimaeras are organisms containing a mixture of genetically different tissues, formed by processes such as fusion of early embryos, grafting, or mutation.